# Getting Jet Report Error "Pivot Table 'PivotTable5' Could Not Be Refreshed...'Reference Is Not Valid.'"

Tags: excel

I am getting the following error when running a Jet Report connected to Dynamics NAV 2013R2: "**Pivot Table 'PivotTable5' Could Not Be Refreshed...'Reference Is Not Valid.'**". I followed the instructions at this link: [Error: The Pivot Table 'PivotTableX' Could Not Be Refreshed...'Reference Is Not Valid.'](https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004577688-Error-The-Pivot-Table-PivotTableX-Could-Not-Be-Refreshed-Reference-is-not-valid-).

The link was helpful, but in my case there are no hidden sheets. Neither are there any #VALUE or any other Excel errors in one of the visible interim sheets (3 or 4) that are created when a Jet Report is being created. The data in the interim sheets is valid data for the Jet Report. The Jet Report runs for a while and appears to be processing normally before throwing the error. Any ideas and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After I had no errors when following the Jet Report support link above, eventually I completely deleted the sheet with the Pivot Table and then reran the Jet Report. This time I got an error dialog saying Invalid Field 'Field Name'. I had copied some formulas into the Jet Report from a similar report and had accidentally copied in a field that did not exist in the current table. It would be nice if they gave you access to that type of error information early on instead of making me eventually hit upon the correct way to identify the error.